# Saving a TXT file and refreshing it every day

Tags: php, function

I made this code which reads a file. All I need is add something which will be saving this file to my server every 24 hours and then reading it from it so this function won't flood "FILE" website.

```
<?php
Define("FILE", "http://www.cnb.cz/cs/financni_trhy/devizovy_trh/kurzy_devizoveho_trhu/denni_kurz.txt");

  function zjistiKurz($mena) {
    $kurzy = file(FILE);
    foreach ($kurzy as $v) {
      $h = explode("|", $v);
      if ((count($h) >= 5) && ($h[3] == $mena)) {
        return $h[2]." ".$h[3]." = ".$h[4]." CZK";
      }
    }
  }
    echo '<span>' . zjistiKurz("EUR") . '</span>';
?>
```

Comment: Cronjob if on linux and Windows Scheduler if on a Windows Server. That's the term you are looking for.

Comment: @DipenShah I need to save copy of that file every 24 hours on my server and the read from it for a day. It's something with PHP I would say.

Comment: Just re-download the file on every first hit to the site for the day. No need to do any cronjob. Keep track if you downloaded a new file today or not, if not download it again, if so, use the saved version.

Comment: @developerwjk Yeah, thanks. Thats what I am looking for, but I couldn't find any code or guide which would show how to do that.

Comment: @Jakub Did you try to research what those terms meant? RTM [cronjob](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) and [Windows Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766428.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it is to check the modified date on the local file, and if its more than 24 hours ago, re-download the file:

```
$localfilepath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/cache/whatever.txt";

if(time() - filemtime($localfilepath) > 86400 ) // Cache every 24 hours: 24*60*60
{
    // download file again
}

// read saved local file
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. I'm looking for something more appropriate. The goal of that code is to show a currency. Defined file is being refreshed more times a day to be honest, but it is okay to save once a day. When does the code which you sent cache the file? Every midnight?

Comment: @Jakub No specific time. Whenever the PHP file is run (i.e. when someone hits it with the browser), if its been more than 24 hours since it last saved the file it saves it again. Of course you just change the number (which is in seconds) to change how frequent you re-download.

Comment: @developerwjk Yeah but the requirement is to run it **every 24 hours** which your code doesn't seem to accomplish. and not run it through a browser. How would you accomplish that?

Comment: @DipenShah You guys think in a tiny box. It depends on the application. Are you downloading this every 24 hours to be used by tons of systems, or just this one? If its just this one, then being so literal like "download every night at precisely midnight" is not necessary. You can download before first use each day. Meaning, say technically 24 hours was 10 hours ago but nobody has used the site yet, then I (or anyone) go to the site, bam it downloads the new file, loads up the local copy it just downloaded, and gives me the proper output. Like I said *this is just one way*.

Comment: @DipenShah Also, if the goal is to save bandwidth for the site you download the file from, this saves MORE bandwidth for them than downloading at an exact time each day. Because if my site goes a whole day without any hits, I never download their file that day. *Again, just one way, not the only way.*

Comment: Yeah, it's okay when it downloads with a first hit, but what would happen if someone visited that site one minute after midnight next day?

Comment: @developerwjk [Oh but the OP doesn't want that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685278/saving-a-txt-file-and-refreshing-it-every-day/34685821?noredirect=1#comment57118723_34685821) And how would you define a *new day*? How will your script know that a new day has occured? you are putting it out blindly without knowing OP's exact requirements. This code might be useful but I don't see a way of doing this without cronjob. Also its incomplete. There is no implementation of how would you achieve it at that specific time.

Comment: @DipenShah It doesn't have to run every 24 hours. The source file is being refreshed by bank every midnight so the function or whatever has to recognize a new day or?

Comment: @Jakub Well, if it has to be exactly midnight, probably better to do a cronjob.

Comment: @Jakub That *function or whatever* is called a cronjob which is a time-based job scheduler.

Comment: Guys, I'm not sure if it has to be that "complicated". I memorized that I was using [this](http://pastebin.com/ds4MyKkK) function for solving this problem, but with XML file. Is that function completed and does it work?

Comment: @DipenShah I don't need it to download a copy of file if nobody visited my site. It's okay to download it with a first hit of a day, but that copy has to be saved there only until the end of day.